# Is an ESTA required for a French/Israeli Citizen travelling last minute to the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I have an emergency (loss of a friend) and I am looking at tickets to the US to leave in a matter of hours. I know an ESTA is valid for 2 years. I travelled to the US for the last time 18 months ago but I do not remember if I used a previous ESTA or not at the time.

I want to buy a ticket for a plane that leaves in 6 hours, if I apply for an ESTA online, will it be ok? They recommend doing it *at least* 72 hours in advance.

Some background: I lived in LA for 11 years with a student visa and never had any trouble with any government agencies (police, immigration etc...). I do not think it will be a problem but I know the immigration agency can be very tedious about their reglementation.

Comment: If you don't have an ESTA how do you plan to enter the US?

Comment: @Karlson I am currently applying for it now, but I'm not sure if it is too alte

Comment: @solalito they're normally issued after a few seconds. Can't you look up your last ESTA to see whether it is still valid?

Comment: @phoog I did some research and saw I indeed did get an ESTA from 18months ago and it is therefore still valid. Sorry for the trouble I needed to get an answer fast and panicked a bit. I'll delete my post.

Comment: @solalito it's no trouble. The site and its users are here to answer questions.  The fact that the question was asked in panic doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the fact that you are in a hurry is **your** problem, not that of the other party (whatever it is a foreign country government, an public organization at your country or a private organization). If you are lucky, you may get a little leeway if you have a valid reason for being in such a hurry (a relative who is ill or has suffered an accident, for example) and you can explain it to the people in charge of deciding, but that is far from granted.

Comment: Note that the ESTA is tied to the passport, so if you had your passport renewed (thereby getting a new passport number), it will presumably no longer be valid. Also, if your dual citizenship comes with dual passports, remember to take the right one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You need an ESTA, either a new one or an old one if it is still valid.

It normally only takes a matter of minutes at most, but there is no guarantee.

You can use the CBP website to [check your ESTA status](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/application.html?execution=e1s1) (use the option for "I Do NOT Know the Application Number"). If you don't have a valid one, apply right away.

Comment: Could he travel using the return ticket of someone with the same name who already has a valid ESTA? :)

Comment: @Berwyn considering that getting a valid ESTA is very fast and customs are understanding of these emergency visits, risking getting caught because the name on a passport doesn't match the one on the visa isn't worthwhile :)

Comment: For context, Berwyn is referencing [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79562/can-two-persons-sharing-a-name-travel-one-way-each-on-a-return-ticket).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an ESTA. The ESTA website will check for you if a valid ESTA exists for your passport. Simply enter a new ESTA and after entering all your information, before submitting payment, the system will warn that there's already a valid ESTA and ask if you want to pay for a new one (don't).